# Best way for picking

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, opengl-es-2.0

After reading the opengl spec => Pixels in the current framebuffer can be read back

so i'm wondering why in some three js example they use 2 buffer one in screen, and one off screen for picking ..

Can someone explain me why ? Why not reading back pixel in the current framebuffer ?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The off screen buffer has an individual colour assigned for each object, this way the current pixel colour identifies the object being picked.

If you use the on screen frame buffer you will not be able to tell which object was picked in case multiple objects have the same colour.